# is the $\epsilon$ term in the definition of a limit arbitrarily large?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

I've understood the definition of the limit $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$ to be:

> for any positive real $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(c)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ given that $|x-c|<\delta$, if and only if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$.

Does this apply even if $f(x)$ doesn't map every $x$ to exactly one element of $y$? Also, can we make $\epsilon$ as big as we wish? If the function is discontinuous as some arbitrary point in the reals, then does $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$ not exist?

Comment: To answer your last question, if a function $f$ is discontinuous at a point $c$, then either $ \lim _{x \rightarrow c} f(x)$ or $f(c)$ does not exist (or both). If they both exist, then they're simply not equal to each other. not to confuse a continuous point with a limit.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question: You want to ask what happens if for the same $x$ there are multiple $y$, say for example $y_1 \neq y_2$ such that $f(x) = y_1$ and $f(x) = y_2$? In this case, $f$ would not be a function and thus we can't just talk about limits.

For the second question, yes, you can make $\epsilon$ as big as you wish. However, if you look up the definition of limit once again, you will see that it says "for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$..."
What you are thinking about is finding a single $\epsilon$ to work with, but you have to consider them all.

For the last question: It depends a little on definitions, but in general one could say that no, the limit does not exist if $f$ is not continuous. In fact, it can be shown that $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ if and only if the limit $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists and satisfies $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

All in all I would suggest that you learn and properly understand the definitions that play in here, there seem to be quite some things mixed up right now.

Comment: For the last part, it might also be worth noting that a limit exists only if its left limit and its right limit both exist and are equivalent --- this is typically how one shows that a limit doesn't exist when a function is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add a thought about the question "can I take $\epsilon $ ad large as I wish ?".

As stated in the previous answer, yes, you can take $\epsilon$ as large as you want. So the question might be turned into: why we usually think/take $\epsilon$ as an arbitrary small number ? The answer is basically that large epsilons **are not useful**. Say a function $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ has an arbitrary bad behavior but satisfies $|f(x)|< 1 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ and we want to investigate its continuity (points). Fix any $l \in (0,1)$, if we take any $\epsilon >> 1$ then it could be true that  $|f(x)-l| < \epsilon $ no matter who is $\delta > 0 $. On the other hand, we have absolutely no control of the actual behavior of $f$ since it can be investigated only at finer scales.